# how to get value property from a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the `value` property of each `checked checkbox` from here:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=marca-chk]:checked").each(function(){        
    bufferTmp.push($(this).prop('value'));
});
```

but with `.prop('value')` I get the `"is checked"` value any idea to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*From the comments by Op:*

The problem is not with the `prop()`, but your `<input>` element does not have attribute `value`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name='marca-chk' val="on">marca-chk1
//                                      ^^^
```

So, you cannot get the property of name `value`, that'll be `undefined`.

**Original Answer**(*Outdated*)

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `prop()` to get the value of checkbox

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
$(this).val()
```

**Code**

```
$("input:checkbox[name=marca-chk]:checked").each(function() {
    bufferTmp.push($(this).val());
    //                    ^^^^^^
});
```

Comment: hmmm  $(this).val() alerts "on" instead of the current value of the checkbox

Comment: got it, i was tiping val instead of value in my HTML, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this).val()` instead of `.prop()` here.

```
$(this).val()
```

The `.prop()` is just for getting the properties of the DOM (eg. `checked`, and `disabled`).

The `.val()` is used for getting the current value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element.

Comment: So what is the difference between `.val()` and `.prop('value')` for `<input type="checkbox" />`?

Comment: @Regent Not much. You cannot toggle the valueless attributes with  `.attr`.

Comment: I actually don't see any difference at all in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evokrfc5/1/). I'm talking only about reading value of `<input type="checkbox" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.prop()`

```js
var bufferTmp = [];
$("input:checkbox[name=marca-chk]:checked").each(function(){        
    bufferTmp.push($(this).val());
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name='marca-chk' value="marca-chk" checked>marca-chk
<input type="checkbox" name='marca-chk1' value="marca-chk1">marca-chk1
```